# Reasons rails is not stopping at debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, testing, breakpoints

In our application in Ruby on Rails (4.0.2) we've always had this problem. I never understood quite well why the application doesn't stop at the debugger statement sometimes.

In some cases, we discovered some constant behavior such as: in a test, it never stops if the statement's placed at the end of the test block like this:

```
  describe '#some_method' do
    it 'should do something as in the requirements etc' do
      model_x = FactoryGirl.create(:model_x)
      model_x.should be_valid

      # ...more code

      model_x.should be_valid

      debugger
    end
  end
```

To make debugger stop at the statement, we have to add a  `p "foo"`
 after it.

In some other misterious cases it doesn't stop, but if you add prints before and after, it does.

When debugging a delayed job, you may have to require the debugger and add some prints for it to stop.

I can't find a deterministic reason why the debugger skips the debugger statement sometimes.

Can someone list the reasons for this behavior?

---

Obs: I'm using byebug right now, but I know that the plain debugger has this behavior too.

Obs2: From my **Gemfile.lock**:

```
byebug (2.4.0)
  columnize (~> 0.3.6)
  debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
...
debugger (1.6.3)
  columnize (>= 0.3.1)
  debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
  debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.4)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in the debugger gem, see [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger#known-issues) (bullet point number three).

It seems that you are interested in *why* it doesn't work. The following is the explanation:

- What debugger does is watching some events provided by ruby that tell the debugger when to stop. In this case, the debugger tracks what we call a `line event` that is triggered once per line executed, so in the case of the last line of a method, the debugger will stop in the next line event, which actually happens outside the method that is being debugged.
- In byebug, however, I also track what we call `return events`, that are called every time a method finishes. That's why I'm able to stop execution before the method actually finishes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps a lot, but still doesn't explain some weird cases like the delayed job debugging. Is it not triggering any 'line event' nor any 'return event'?

Comment: You mean it just never stops? That's weird, it should always stop.